# How to share post to G+ Twitter and Facebook

Tags: facebook, twitter, blog, google-plus

I have fb profile connected to twitter and when I write to twitter it will be shared to fb profile

I have G+Twitter plugin which will post to twitter since I post to G+ but it doesn't share the post to fb.

is there some way to merge those 3 services somehow? I heard about some weird way of making it using sms and phone number but I'm looking for method without sms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use the awesome IFTTT to handle such trigger.

Here are two recipes for Facebook and Twitter:

- [Blog post to Facebook](https://ifttt.com/recipes/8100)
- [Blog post to Twitter](https://ifttt.com/recipes/5539)

For Google Plus, it seems to be more complicated. If you have a wordpress blog, it will be easy with [this recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/5471). Otherwise, you can customize [this one](https://ifttt.com/recipes/20230) (which is Twitter to G+).

Comment: yes http://google-plus.com/2053/how-to-post-to-google-using-email-or-gmail-you-can-post-to-public-circles-extended-circles-etc/ - it's what I had found but it's to complex... isn't there easier way? maybe post from Google+ to fb somehow alike I do with twitter?

Comment: Well, I recommend you to [search for Google Plus on IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/recipes/search?q=google+plus). You might find some other ways to do it.

Comment: still can't find something instead of sms but maybe I shell try that.

Comment: If you find something interesting, share it! :-)

Comment: Alright, so far - nothing really useful =)